# PTIJ: Who would win in an all-out Brawl?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

**The showdown of biblical proportions!**

Who would win in a fight between the major characters in Tanach?
The rules:

1. No magical weapons (i.e. Moshe's staff is banned)
2. Character's fight in their prime (I leave this to your discretion, but no kicking Yitzchak when he's already blind, for instance)
3. Hashem doesn't intervene and play favorites

Bonus points if you would like to create your own tier list! Here's mine for an example:

S tier: Samson (assuming hair and eyes)

A tier: David, Yael, Elisha (w/ bears), Adam

B tier: Moshe, Jacob, Avraham, Shimon + Levi (tag team)

C tier: Noah, Joshua, Cain

D tier: Joseph, Saul, Isaac, Aharon, Balaam’s donkey

F tier: Shlomo (nerd), Samuel, Abel, Balaam, Ezra?, Job , Lot

? tier: Daniel, Mordechai, Elijah, Esau, Isaiah, Yehuda, Reuven, Eliyahu

I look forward to hearing everyone's answers! Chag Sameach!

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Please remember to include the footer

Comment: How are Elisha's bears not a magical weapon? And Moshe's staff is?

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if you know Adam Hareishon in his Prime (before the sin). One side of the world to the other. (Even after the sin, he's 100 amos tall).That's an instant K.O , if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I go with David. David was a true warrior and soldier because as a youngster, he defeated the mighty giant Goliath with a sling.

Comment: Over there a neis happened that his armor became weak and the rock went through it.